# Rearrange a Python List

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to rearrange a python list in this form:

```
[(title1,x1,y1),(title1,x2,y2),(title2,x3,y3),(title2,x4,y4),...]
```

And I need to rearrange it to this:

```
{title1:{
    x1:y1,
    x2:y2
},
title2:{
    x3:y3,
    x4:y4
}}
```

The output just needs to look the same and does not have to be an actual python list.
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(dict)

for title, x, y in my_list:
    res[title][x] = y
```